# Counting consecutive names

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have a list of names. They are sorted by the year that they were the most popular female baby name of that year. In the following function I am to report the name that appears the most consecutively in a given year range. I am testing in the range 2004 to 2007.

The list for that is the following:

```
['Emily','Emily','Emily','Isabel']
```

The desired output is:

```
Emily occurred consecutively the most in this range at 3 time/s
```

However I get

```
Emily occurred consecutively the most in this range at 2 time/s
```

I will post my code below.

example I was given to follow.

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
bestName = 'A', bestCount = 1, currentName = 'A', currentCount = 1

['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], next name = 'A'
currentName = nextName, so currentCount = 2

[ 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], next name = 'B'
currentName != nextName, and currentCount > bestCount, so bestName = 'A', bestCount = 2, 
now currentName = 'B', currentCount = 1

['C', 'C', 'C'] next name = 'C'
currentName != nextName, and currentCount not greater than bestCount
now currentName = 'C', currentCount = 1

['C', 'C'] next name = 'C'
currentName = nextName, so currentCount = 2

['C'] next name = 'C'
currentName = nextName, so currentCount = 3

[] no next name, loop ends
currentCount > bestCount, so bestName = 'C', bestCount = 3
```

And the code:

```
def mostConsecutiveYears(names):
    """
    Compute which name occurs the most times consecutively in a
    list of names.
    :param names (list of Name): A list of name objects
    :return: A tuple containing best name (str) and the count (int)
    :rtype: tuple
    """
    bestName = names[0].name
    bestCount = 1
    currentName = names[0].name
    currentCount = 1

    for i in range(1,len(names)):
        if names[i].name == currentName:
            currentCount += 1

        if currentCount > bestCount:
            bestName = currentName
            bestCount = currentCount
            currentCount = 1
            currentName = names[i].name

    if currentCount > bestCount:
        bestName = currentName
        bestCount = currentCount

    return bestName, bestCount
```

Comment: I tried, but I still don't think the indention is correct. Can you fix your indention?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: It is now identical to what I have in my IDE.

Comment: I think you need a double for loop, or a more clever solution. It look like you're trying to keep a running count/max, while counting how many occurrences of each name occurred. That lends towards a double for loop.

Comment: I would take a look at `itertools.groupby`

Comment: I have an example that I will add to the question to help show what I am looking for in finding the solution.

Comment: I believe a suggested answer was deleted. It believe it was not correct either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like that (note that `names` is a string list in my code)

```
def mostConsecutiveYears(names):
    """
    Compute which name occurs the most times consecutively in a
    list of names.
    :param names (list of Name): A list of name objects
    :return: A tuple containing best name (str) and the count (int)
    :rtype: tuple
    """
    bestName = names[0] # Be careful you can get an error if your list is empty
    bestCount = 1
    currentName = names[0]
    currentCount = 1

    for name in names[1:]:

        if name == currentName:
            currentCount += 1
        else:
            currentCount = 1
            currentName = name

        if currentCount > bestCount:
            bestName = currentName
            bestCount = currentCount

    return bestName, bestCount

print(mostConsecutiveYears(['Emily','Emily','Emily','Isabel']))
```

Comment: Not completely correct. If I have a list `[a,b,b,b,b,b,b,c,c,d,d]` it will return c as the most consecutive instead of b.

Comment: Answer is close but there is another case where I have `[a,a,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,c,c]`. it will return c consecutive 6 times instead of 7. This is the error iI had at first.

Comment: and if I change where the else and second if is, it will return a as the most consecutive.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, the script works on my side. It returns 7 as expected

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `itertools.groupby`.  This isn't a full solution, but should give you an idea of how to proceed.

```
names = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
names = ['Emily', 'Emily', 'Emily', 'Isabel', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Isabel', 'Emily']
groups = []
for a, b in itertools.groupby(names):
    items = list(b)
    groups.append((len(items), a))

count, name = sorted(groups, reverse=True)[0]
print("{} occurred consecutively the most in this range at {} time{}".format(name, count, "s" if count > 1 else ""))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Emily occurred consecutively the most in this range at 3 times
```

The real question is how you want to handle input like

```
['Emily', 'Isabel', 'Mary']
```